# Can I create a virtual ALSA source without snd-aloop or sudo?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I am working with a Pepper robot that unfortunately does not allow for sudo access. The robot has a 4-mic array, and I would like to create a virtual ALSA device that merges the 4 mics with the speaker output, so Azure can perform echo-cancelled speech recognition. I want a virtual ALSA device, not a Pulse source, because Azure Speech SDK only supports ALSA.

Ordinarily, this wouldn't be hard to achieve with the snd-aloop ALSA module, but without root I can't activate that. PulseAudio seems to be more friendly for non-root use, I guess my question is whether it's possible to create a new virtual input/microphone in ALSA and route my PulseAudio stream to that device, without the use of snd-aloop.